# csvsimple usage in beamer class

Tags: beamer, csvsimple

Why does this work

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents,csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{chunk.csv}
line one
line two
line three
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[no head]{chunk.csv}{}{
    \begin{frame}
        \csvcoli
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

while this doesn't:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents,csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{chunk.csv}
line one
line two
line three
\end{filecontents*}

\csvreader[no head,before line=\begin{frame},late after line=\end{frame}]{chunk.csv}{}{\csvcoli}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is not really related to `csvsimple`. You get the same kind of compilation error, if you use the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bframe}{\begin{frame}}
\newcommand{\eframe}{\end{frame}}

\bframe
Test
\eframe

\end{document}
```

The same thing happens, when you give `\begin{frame}` to `before line` and `\end{frame}` to `late after line`. A beamer frame is a highly sophisticated environment which cannot easily split like that.

Comment: Bummer, I had hoped for a different kind of answer :-(    ... but thanks anyway.